# how to use web3j geting inputparams

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

```
public static List<Type> readTx(String inputData, String abi, String methodName){
        ABIUtils abiUtils = new ABIUtils();
        try {
            String abi4Json = abiUtils.getABI4Json(abi);
            ArrayList<TypeReference<Type>> transfer = abiUtils.getInputTypeReferences(methodName, abi4Json);
            return FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(inputData, transfer);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JsonProcessingException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public  ArrayList<TypeReference<Type>> getInputTypeReferences(String methodName, String abi) throws ClassNotFoundException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        AbiDefinition[] abiDefinitions = om.readValue(abi, AbiDefinition[].class);
        AbiDefinition function = Arrays.stream(abiDefinitions).filter(abiDefinition -> {
            if (abiDefinition.getType().equals("function")) {
                return abiDefinition.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName);
            }
            return false;
        }).findFirst().orElse(null);

        ArrayList<TypeReference<Type>> functionsRef = new ArrayList<>();

        for (AbiDefinition.NamedType namedType : function.getInputs()) {
            String type = namedType.getType();
            TypeReference typeReference = TypeReference.makeTypeReference(type);
            functionsRef.add(typeReference);
        }
        return functionsRef;
    }
```

how to use web3j geting inputparams ,this code ?Here I want to use abi to directly obtain the execution parameters of the contract, is there anything that needs to be changed

Here I want to use abi to directly obtain the execution parameters of the contract, is there anything that needs to be changed